# Java Gui GridLayout- accessing objects

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to make a connect four gui.

I have a class Gui which creates a board ( an array[][] ints) and a method move- which accepts the player(int) and column(int)- and a method to check if there is a winner.

I created a gui with the gridLayout and I have a row of buttons and 7 arrays of JLabels (that are an ImageIcon of empty slot) I need to now access the bottommost JLabel of a specific array if a player chooses that column.

**I created the buttons in a loop:**

1. A) how do I access each button- they do not have unique names.
2. B) how do I access each JLabels- they were also created in a loop
3. C) where am I suppose to instantiate my Board Class?
4. D) when I am adding each new object in the gui I have
   this.add(JLabel)--

**how do I put all that into a new Panel so I can have a title bar on top of my grid?**

my code for the gui

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class ConnectFourGui extends JFrame {

private JLabel title;
private JButton button;
ImageIcon[] emptySlot;
ImageIcon arrow;

public ConnectFourGui() {
    this.setTitle("Connect Four");
    this.setSize(800, 800);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    //Container container = this.getContentPane();
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 7));

    this.title = new JLabel("Connect Four");
    title.setForeground(Color.RED);
    title.setFont(new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.BOLD, 50));
    title.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);


    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        arrow = new ImageIcon("arrowButton.png");
        this.button = new JButton(arrow);
        this.add(button);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        emptySlot = new ImageIcon[6];
        for (int j = 0; j<6;j++){
            emptySlot[j] = new ImageIcon("emptySlot.png");
            this.add(new JLabel(emptySlot[j]));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making seperate arrays for each column like this (see code below). Also make your array an array of JLabels instead of ImageIcons. And create each button with a unique name.

```
column1 = new JLabel[6];
    column2 = new JLabel[6];
    column3 = new JLabel[6];
    column4 = new JLabel[6];
    column5 = new JLabel[6];
    column6 = new JLabel[6];
    column7 = new JLabel[6];

    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        column1[j] = new JLabel(emptySlot);
        column2[j] = new JLabel(emptySlot);
        column3[j] = new JLabel(emptySlot);
        column4[j] = new JLabel(emptySlot);
        column5[j] = new JLabel(emptySlot);
        column6[j] = new JLabel(emptySlot);
        column7[j] = new JLabel(emptySlot);
        this.add(column1[j]);
        this.add(column2[j]);
        this.add(column3[j]);
        this.add(column4[j]);
        this.add(column5[j]);
        this.add(column6[j]);
        this.add(column7[j]);
    }
```

To accces an element in the array per the button on top do something like this

```
buttonName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            column1[3].setIcon(newIcon);
}
}
```

- you would be using a variable instead of the number 3 I used as an example

Instantiate your board class in your constructor.